# MinOrDefault extension is not supported

Tags: c#, linq

I just would like to confirm that

```
Collection.Min(p => p.Value);
```

Works only if the Collection is not empty and there is no MinOrEmpty or something similar, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to return the default value for the element type if it's empty, that's easy:

```
var min = Collection.Select(p => p.Value).DefaultIfEmpty().Min();
```

Alternatively, if you want a particular minimum value:

```
var min = Collection.Select(p => p.Value)
                    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(int.Minvalue, 1)
                    .Min();
```

Or:

```
var min = Collection.Select(p => (int?) p.Value)
                    .Min(); // min will be the null value if Collection is empty
```

Is that what you're after? It's not entirely clear.

`Min` and `Max` behave slightly differently for empty sequences of non-nullable element types than for empty sequences of nullable element types. When the element type is nullable, the null value is returned if and only if the sequence is empty; for non-nullable element types, `InvalidOperationException` is thrown. See my [Edulinq blog post on Min/Max](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/09/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-29-min-max.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If the collection contains nullable types -- either reference types or `Nullable<T>` values -- then the `Min` method will return `null` if the collection is empty.

If the collection contains non-nullable value types then the `Min` method will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the collection is empty.

Note that in your example, where you're passing a delegate to the `Min` method, then the behaviour is determined by the delegate's return type, *not* the type of the elements themselves.

(And no, there's no built-in `MinOrEmpty` method. There are plenty of easy alternatives though, [see Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550634/minordefault-extension-is-not-supported/5550696#5550696) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is empty is does not make sense to compute the minimum value. However, if you want to return a specific value if the sequence is empty you can do it like this (assuming that your a computing the minimum of `int` values):

```
int defaultMinValue = -1;
var min = Collection.Select(p => p.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultMinValue).Min();
```

If the sequence is empty it will return -1, otherwise it will compute the the minimum value of the sequence.